# Where should VSTO-developed extensions be installed?

Tags: excel, deployment, vsto

I am building an extension ribbon for Excel.  Besides the ribbon DLL I will have a data access DLL and a .sdf (SQL CE database file).  In which directories should they be installed?  Is there a best practice for deploying this project?  It will be used at several sites around the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I install vsto addins just like any other addin or application. I have the installer create a \program files\MyCompany\MyApp folder, put the dlls, and the addin's Manifest and config files right there. Maybe create a few subfolders to store other info. then Register the addin and point to that location.

Comment: This was an old and dusty question, thanks for bothering to answer--Jay